# Dynamic Dropdown with Streamlit or Dash

Tags: python, plotly-dash, streamlit

I'm working on a small project where I would like to visualize a DataFrame using `python` + `streamlit`. The user should be able to filter on three different columns where the options which should be available depend on each other.
A minimal example is given by the DataFrame below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "continent": ["Asia"] * 2 + ["Europe"] * 2 + ["North America"] * 2,
        "country": ["China", "Japan"]
        + ["United Kingdom", "France"]
        + ["United States", "Canada"],
        "language": ["Chinese", "Japanese"]
        + ["English", "French"]
        + ["English", "English"],
    }
)
```

The user should be able to select `continent`, `country` and `language`.

Example 1: The user selects `continent = North America` which should reduce the options for the country menu to `United States` and `Canada` and the languages to `English`.
As a next step, if the user switches from `continent = America` to `continent = Europe`, the second menu should reduce to the countries in Europe and the languages spoken in these countries.

Example 2: The user starts by selection `language = English`. As as a result the options for `continent` reduce to `North America` and `Europe` since the countries in which English is spoken are `Canada`, the `United States` and the `United Kingdom`.

The problem is, that the values depend on each other in a non-linear fashion. I've tried to solve this problem with `streamlit` and `callback` but from reading other questions my impression is that `streamlit` is not designed for complex dependencies.

I've not yet worked with `Dash`. Before I start working on this by copy-pasting code from the internet my question is whether it is possible to build these complex dependencies with `dash`?

**Update**

I was able to build an MVP with `streamlit` using the code at the end. The dropdown menus are dynamic which is what I was looking for (Image 1). But because the dropdown options depend on the filtered DataFrame, once a selection was made, the only way back is to use the `Refresh Data` button which is not very user friendly (Image 2).

Image 1: Without selection
[image]

Image 2: After the first selection
[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

st.set_page_config(page_title="Toy App", layout="wide")


@st.cache
def get_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Continent": ["Asia"] * 2 + ["Europe"] * 2 + ["North America"] * 2,
            "Country": ["China", "Japan"]
            + ["United Kingdom", "France"]
            + ["United States", "Canada"],
            "Language": ["Chinese", "Japanese"]
            + ["English", "French"]
            + ["English", "English"],
        }
    )
    return df


def update_df(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    continent = st.session_state["Continent"]
    country = st.session_state["Country"]
    language = st.session_state["Language"]
    if continent != "all":
        df = df.query(f"Continent == '{continent}'")
    if country != "all":
        df = df.query(f"Country == '{country}'")
    if language != "all":
        df = df.query(f"Language == '{language}'")
    st.session_state["df"] = df
    st.session_state["fresh_data"] = False


df = get_data()


if "df" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.df = df
if "fresh_data" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.fresh_data = True

with st.expander("Display", expanded=True):
    if st.button("Refresh data"):
        df = get_data()
        st.session_state["df"] = df
        st.session_state["fresh_data"] = True

    df = st.session_state["df"]
    col1, col2, col3 = st.columns(3)

    continent_options = df.Continent.unique().tolist()
    country_options = df.Country.unique().tolist()
    language_options = df.Language.unique().tolist()

    if st.session_state.fresh_data:
        country_options.insert(0, "all")
        language_options.insert(0, "all")
        continent_options.insert(0, "all")

    continent = col1.selectbox(
        "Continent",
        options=continent_options,
        on_change=update_df,
        kwargs={"df": df},
        key="Continent",
    )
    countries = col2.selectbox(
        "Country",
        options=country_options,
        on_change=update_df,
        kwargs={"df": df},
        key="Country",
    )
    language = col3.selectbox(
        "Language",
        options=language_options,
        on_change=update_df,
        kwargs={"df": df},
        key="Language",
    )

    st.write(df.astype("object"))
```

Comment: The simple answer is yes, Dash can do that, even with complex dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `callback` to return `options` for each `dropdown` based on others `dropdown` value. Please refer below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.Span('Continent',className='text-center'),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='continent',placeholder="Please select continent",
                         options=[{'label':x,'value':x} for x in df2.sort_values('continent')['continent'].unique()],
                         value=[],
                         multi=True,
                         disabled=False,
                         clearable=True,
                         searchable=True),
        ],width={'size':4,"offset":0,'order':1}),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Span('Country',className='text-center'),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='country',placeholder="Please select country", # Dropdown for heatmap color
                         options=[{'label':x,'value':x} for x in df2.sort_values('country')['country'].unique()],
                         value=[],
                         multi=True,
                         disabled=False,
                         clearable=True,
                         searchable=True)
        ],width={'size':4,'offset':0,'order':1}),
        dbc.Col([
            html.Span('Language',className='text-center'),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='language',placeholder="Please select language", # Dropdown for heatmap color
                         options=[{'label':x,'value':x} for x in df2.sort_values('language')['language'].unique()],
                         value=[],
                         multi=True,
                         disabled=False,
                         clearable=True,
                         searchable=True)
        ],width={'size':4,'offset':0,'order':1}),        
    ], className='p-2 align-items-stretch')
])

@app.callback(Output('continent','options'),
             [Input('country','value'),
              Input('language','value')])

def update_options(country,language):
    if country != [] and language != []:
        dff = df2[df2['country'].isin(country)]
        df3 = dff[dff['language'].isin(language)]
    elif country != [] and language == []:
        df3 = df2[df2['country'].isin(country)]
    elif country == [] and language != []:   
        df3 = df2[df2['language'].isin(language)]    
    else:
        df3 = df2.copy()
    return [{'label':x,'value':x} for x in df3.sort_values('continent')['continent'].unique()]

@app.callback(Output('country','options'),
             [Input('continent','value'),
              Input('language','value')])

def update_options(continent,language):
    if continent != [] and language != []:
        dff = df2[df2['continent'].isin(continent)]
        df3 = dff[dff['language'].isin(language)]
    elif continent != [] and language == []:
        df3 = df2[df2['continent'].isin(continent)]
    elif continent == [] and language != []:   
        df3 = df2[df2['language'].isin(language)]    
    else:
        df3 = df2.copy()
    return [{'label':x,'value':x} for x in df3.sort_values('country')['country'].unique()]

@app.callback(Output('language','options'),
             [Input('continent','value'),
              Input('country','value')])

def update_options(continent,country):
    if continent != [] and country != []:
        dff = df2[df2['continent'].isin(continent)]
        df3 = dff[dff['country'].isin(country)]
    elif continent != [] and country == []:
        df3 = df2[df2['continent'].isin(continent)]
    elif continent == [] and country != []:   
        df3 = df2[df2['country'].isin(country)]    
    else:
        df3 = df2.copy()
    return [{'label':x,'value':x} for x in df3.sort_values('language')['language'].unique()]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False,port=1116)
```

And below is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do what you are looking for

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

def value_change(category):
    st.session_state.df = st.session_state.df[st.session_state.df[category]==st.session_state[category]]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "continent": ["Asia"] * 2 + ["Europe"] * 2 + ["North America"] * 2,
        "country": ["China", "Japan"]
        + ["United Kingdom", "France"]
        + ["United States", "Canada"],
        "language": ["Chinese", "Japanese"]
        + ["English", "French"]
        + ["English", "English"],
    }
)


if 'df' not in st.session_state or st.button('Reset'):
    st.session_state.df = df

cols = st.columns(3)
continent = cols[0].selectbox('Continent', st.session_state.df.continent.unique(), key='continent' , on_change=value_change, kwargs={'category': 'continent'})
country   = cols[1].selectbox('Country', st.session_state.df.country.unique(), key='country' , on_change=value_change, kwargs={'category': 'country'})
language  = cols[2].selectbox('Language', st.session_state.df.language.unique(), key='language' , on_change=value_change, kwargs={'category': 'language'})

st.dataframe(st.session_state.df)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is similar to a version I was able to build with streamlit. But after the first selection, f.e. 'Asia' it's not possible to select another continent since the DataFrame is filtered.

Comment: Just add a button to reset the options.

Comment: I did. But doesn't  feel very user friendly. Especially if one want's to switch between different options in an intermediate dropdown, f.e. switch between countries after having selected `continent=Europe`.

Comment: The reset button in the code is just an example. You can try providing a reset as an option in the dropdown to clear out the constraints for that category. Or you can design `st.multiselect` box, which determines what will be shown in the final dropdown menu.