# IndexError: list index out of range in chained callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash

How the second dropdown list can automatically show value based on the first dropdown list?
Only one value is available for the second dropdown list based on the selection in first dropdown list.

**Sample data:**

```
data = {'Product ID': {0: 'P1', 1: 'P2', 2: 'P3', 3: 'P4', 4: 'P5', 5: 'P1', 6: 'P2', 7: 'P3', 8: 'P4', 9: 'P5'}, 'Sale ID': {0: 'Sale 001', 1: 'Sale 002', 2: 'Sale 003', 3: 'Sale 004', 4: 'Sale 005', 5: 'Sale 006', 6: 'Sale 007', 7: 'Sale 008', 8: 'Sale 009', 9: 'Sale 010'},  'Tnx Amount': {0: 100.0, 1: 101.0, 2: 102.0, 3: 103.0, 4: 104.0, 5: 100.0, 6: 101.0, 7: 102.0, 8: 103.0, 9: 104.0}, 'Tnx Date': {0: '01/10/2022', 1: '02/10/2022', 2: '03/10/2022', 3: '04/10/2022', 4: '05/10/2022', 5: '06/10/2022', 6: '07/10/2022', 7: '08/10/2022', 8: '09/10/2022', 9: '10/10/2022'}, 'Customer ID': {0: 'Cus01', 1: 'Cus02', 2: 'Cus03', 3: 'Cus04', 4: 'Cus05', 5: 'Cus01', 6: 'Cus02', 7: 'Cus03', 8: 'Cus04', 9: 'Cus05'}}
```

**Code:**

`app.layout`

```
app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.H1("Tes",
                        className = 'text-center text-primary, mb-4 '
                        ,style={"textDecoration":"underline",'font-weight': 'bold'}),
                width=12
                ),
      
        ]),
    html.Br(),
    
    dbc.Row([
       dbc.Col([
           html.H3('Product'
                    ,style={'font-size': '25px'}
                   ),
           
           ], width=3, md=4),
       
       dbc.Col([            
           dcc.Dropdown(id='product_dd', value= None, #df['year'].max(),
                          options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                                    for x in product_cat],
                          
                          searchable = True, search_value='',
                          placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                          clearable= True
                          ),
           
           ], width=3, md=4),    
       
       
       ]),
    html.Br(),
    
    
    
    dbc.Row([       
        dbc.Col([            
            html.H3('Date'
                    ,style={'font-size': '25px'}
                    ),
            
            ], width=3, md=4),
    
        dbc.Col([            
            dcc.Dropdown(id='date_dd', value= '',                         
                          searchable = True, search_value='',
                          placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                          clearable=True
                          
                          ),
            html.Br(),
            
            ], width=3, md=4),
        ], ), #style={"flexWrap": "wrap", "width":"250px"}
    html.Br(),
            
    dbc.Row([
          dbc.Col([
            html.H3('Sale ID'
                    ,style={'font-size': '25px'}
                    ),

              ], width=3, md=4),
          
          dbc.Col([          
              dcc.Dropdown(id='saleid_dd', value='',
                          searchable = True, search_value='',
                          placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                          clearable=True
                          ),
                  
              html.Br(),
              
              ], width=3, md=4),
          

          ]),
    
    html.Br(), 
               
    dbc.Row([
       dbc.Col([
           html.H3('Customer ID'
                    ,style={'font-size': '25px'}
                   ),
           
           ], width=3, md=4),
       
       dbc.Col([            
           dcc.Dropdown(id='customer_dd', value= '',                         
                          searchable = True, search_value='',
                          placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                          clearable= True
                          ),
           html.Br(),
           
           ], width=3, md=4),    
       
       
       ]),
    html.Br(),
            
])
```

`@callback`

```
@app.callback(
    Output('date_dd','options'),
    Input('product_dd', 'value')
    )


def update_dd (product_dd):
  
    date = df.drop_duplicates(['Date'], inplace= False)
    
    relevant_date = date[ df['Product'] == product_dd]['Date'].values.tolist()

    date_option= [dict(label=x,value=x)for x in relevant_date]
    
    
    return date_option


#first dropdown
@app.callback(
    Output('saleid_dd','options'),
    Input('date_dd', 'value')
    )


def update_dd (date_dd):
       
    saleid= df.drop_duplicates(['Sale ID'], inplace= False)
    
    relevant_id= saleid[ df['Date'] == date_dd]['Sale ID'].values.tolist()
    saleid_option= [dict(label=x,value=x)for x in relevant_id]
    
    
    return saleid_option



#second dropdown
@app.callback(
    Output('customer_dd','options'),
    Input('saleid_dd', 'value')
    )


def update_dd (saleid_dd):
  
    customer = df.drop_duplicates(['Customer ID'], inplace= False)
    
    relevant_customer = customer[ df['Sale ID'] == saleid_dd]['Customer ID'].values.tolist()

    cust_option= [dict(label=x,value=x)for x in relevant_customer]
    
    
    return cust_option
    

@app.callback(
    Output('customer_dd','value'),
    Input('customer_dd', 'options')
    )


def default_value(merchant):    
    return merchant[0]['value']
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as text, not as images. Also, check your formatting.

Comment: Please write `df.head(10).to_dict()` and copy and paste the result to your question instead of the images.

Comment: Thanks, now add a full example by adding `app.layout` because you only added callbacks

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear. You want to fill the second dropdown menu based on the selection of first dropdown menu, right?

Comment: Yes, the second dropdown menu able to auto display the value based on the first dropdown menu.

Comment: You filled the Product menu with the columns of dataframe, is that what you are trying to do? Because the name of each dropdown menu is a column in the dataframe. Therefore, each dropdown menu should be filled with a column independently, right?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: So there is no need to link between the first and the second dropdown menus.

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly you need to add options in your layout first and then use callback to return new options. Please refer below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {'Product ID': {0: 'P1', 1: 'P2', 2: 'P3', 3: 'P4', 4: 'P5', 5: 'P1', 6: 'P2', 7: 'P3', 8: 'P4', 9: 'P5'}, 'Sale ID': {0: 'Sale 001', 1: 'Sale 002', 2: 'Sale 003', 3: 'Sale 004', 4: 'Sale 005', 5: 'Sale 006', 6: 'Sale 007', 7: 'Sale 008', 8: 'Sale 009', 9: 'Sale 010'},  'Tnx Amount': {0: 100.0, 1: 101.0, 2: 102.0, 3: 103.0, 4: 104.0, 5: 100.0, 6: 101.0, 7: 102.0, 8: 103.0, 9: 104.0}, 'Tnx Date': {0: '01/10/2022', 1: '02/10/2022', 2: '03/10/2022', 3: '04/10/2022', 4: '05/10/2022', 5: '06/10/2022', 6: '07/10/2022', 7: '08/10/2022', 8: '09/10/2022', 9: '10/10/2022'}, 'Customer ID': {0: 'Cus01', 1: 'Cus02', 2: 'Cus03', 3: 'Cus04', 4: 'Cus05', 5: 'Cus01', 6: 'Cus02', 7: 'Cus03', 8: 'Cus04', 9: 'Cus05'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.H1("Tes",
                        className = 'text-center text-primary, mb-4 '
                        ,style={"textDecoration":"underline",'font-weight': 'bold'}),
                width=12
                ),
      
        ]),
    html.Br(),
    
    dbc.Row([
       dbc.Col([
           html.H3('Product'
                    ,style={'font-size': '25px'}
                   ),
           
           ], width=3, md=4),
       
       dbc.Col([            
           dcc.Dropdown(id='product_dd',
                        options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                                    for x in df['Product ID'].unique()],
                        value=[],
                        searchable = True,
                        placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                        multi=True,
                        clearable= True)
           ], width=3, md=4),    
       ]),
    html.Br(),
    dbc.Row([       
        dbc.Col([            
            html.H3('Date'
                    ,style={'font-size': '25px'}
                    )], width=3, md=4),
        dbc.Col([            
            dcc.Dropdown(id='date_dd', 
                         options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                                    for x in df['Tnx Date'].unique()],
                         value=[],
                         searchable = True,
                         placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                         clearable=True,
                        multi=True,),
            html.Br(),
        ], width=3, md=4),
    ]), #style={"flexWrap": "wrap", "width":"250px"}
    html.Br(),
 
    dbc.Row([
          dbc.Col([
            html.H3('Sale ID'
                    ,style={'font-size': '25px'})
          ], width=3, md=4),
          
          dbc.Col([          
              dcc.Dropdown(id='saleid_dd',
                           options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                                    for x in df['Sale ID'].unique()],
                           value=[],
                           searchable = True,
                           placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                           clearable=True,
                        multi=True,
                          ),
              html.Br(),
          
          ], width=3, md=4),
    ]),
    html.Br(), 
               
    dbc.Row([
       dbc.Col([
           html.H3('Customer ID'
                    ,style={'font-size': '25px'}
                  )
       ], width=3, md=4),
       
       dbc.Col([            
           dcc.Dropdown(id='customer_dd',
                        options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                                    for x in df['Customer ID'].unique()], 
                        value=[],
                        searchable = True,
                        placeholder= 'Please select ...',
                        clearable= True,
                        multi=True,
                       ),
           html.Br(),
       ], width=3, md=4),
    ]),
    html.Br(),
])


@app.callback(
    Output('product_dd','options'),
    [Input('date_dd', 'value'), 
    Input('saleid_dd','value'),
    Input('customer_dd','value')]
    )

def update_dd (date_dd,saleid_dd,customer_dd):
    if date_dd != [] and saleid_dd != [] and customer_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]
        df2 = df1[df1['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]
        dff = df2[df2['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)]       
    elif date_dd != [] and saleid_dd == [] and customer_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]
        dff = df1[df1['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)]          
    elif date_dd != [] and saleid_dd != [] and customer_dd == []:
        df1 = df[df['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]
        dff = df1[df1['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]      
    elif date_dd != [] and saleid_dd == [] and customer_dd == []:
        dff = df[df['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]
    elif date_dd == [] and saleid_dd != [] and customer_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]       
        dff = df1[df1['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)]
    elif date_dd == [] and saleid_dd != [] and customer_dd == []:
        dff = df[df['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]       
    elif date_dd == [] and saleid_dd == [] and customer_dd != []:
        dff = df[df['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)] 
    elif date_dd == [] and saleid_dd == [] and customer_dd == []:
        dff = df.copy()
    return [{'label':x,'value':x} for x in dff['Product ID'].unique()]



@app.callback(
    Output('date_dd','options'),
    [Input('product_dd', 'value'),
    Input('saleid_dd','value'),
    Input('customer_dd','value')]
    )

def update_dd (product_dd,saleid_dd,customer_dd):
    if product_dd != [] and saleid_dd != [] and customer_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)]
        df2 = df1[df1['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]
        dff = df2[df2['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)]       
    elif product_dd != [] and saleid_dd == [] and customer_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)]
        dff = df1[df1['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)]          
    elif product_dd != [] and saleid_dd != [] and customer_dd == []:
        df1 = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)]
        dff = df1[df1['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]      
    elif product_dd != [] and saleid_dd == [] and customer_dd == []:
        dff = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)]
    elif product_dd == [] and saleid_dd != [] and customer_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]       
        dff = df1[df1['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)]
    elif product_dd == [] and saleid_dd != [] and customer_dd == []:
        dff = df[df['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]       
    elif product_dd == [] and saleid_dd == [] and customer_dd != []:
        dff = df[df['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)] 
    elif product_dd == [] and saleid_dd == [] and customer_dd == []:
        dff = df.copy()
    return [{'label':x,'value':x} for x in dff['Tnx Date'].unique()]

@app.callback(
    Output('saleid_dd','options'),
    [Input('product_dd', 'value'), 
    Input('date_dd','value'), 
    Input('customer_dd','value')]
    )

def update_dd (product_dd,date_dd,customer_dd):
    if product_dd != [] and date_dd != [] and customer_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)]        
        df2 = df1[df1['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]
        dff = df2[df2['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)]       
    elif product_dd != [] and date_dd == [] and customer_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)] 
        dff = df1[df1['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)]          
    elif product_dd != [] and date_dd != [] and customer_dd == []:
        df1 = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)] 
        dff = df1[df1['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]      
    elif product_dd != [] and date_dd == [] and customer_dd == []:
        dff = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)] 
    elif product_dd == [] and date_dd != [] and customer_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]       
        dff = df1[df1['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)]
    elif product_dd == [] and date_dd != [] and customer_dd == []:
        dff = df[df['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]        
    elif product_dd == [] and date_dd == [] and customer_dd != []:
        dff = df[df['Customer ID'].isin(customer_dd)] 
    elif product_dd == [] and date_dd == [] and customer_dd == []:
        dff = df.copy()
    return [{'label':x,'value':x} for x in dff['Sale ID'].unique()]

@app.callback(
    Output('customer_dd','options'), 
    [Input('product_dd', 'value'), 
    Input('date_dd','value'), 
    Input('saleid_dd','value')]
    )

def update_dd (product_dd,date_dd,saleid_dd):
    if product_dd != [] and date_dd != [] and saleid_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)]        
        df2 = df1[df1['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]
        dff = df2[df2['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]       
    elif product_dd != [] and date_dd == [] and saleid_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)] 
        dff = df1[df1['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]          
    elif product_dd != [] and date_dd != [] and saleid_dd == []:
        df1 = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)] 
        dff = df1[df1['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]      
    elif product_dd != [] and date_dd == [] and saleid_dd == []:
        dff = df[df['Product ID'].isin(product_dd)] 
    elif product_dd == [] and date_dd != [] and saleid_dd != []:
        df1 = df[df['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]       
        dff = df1[df1['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)]
    elif product_dd == [] and date_dd != [] and saleid_dd == []:
        dff = df[df['Tnx Date'].isin(date_dd)]        
    elif product_dd == [] and date_dd == [] and saleid_dd != []:
        dff = df[df['Sale ID'].isin(saleid_dd)] 
    elif product_dd == [] and date_dd == [] and saleid_dd == []:
        dff = df.copy()
    return [{'label':x,'value':x} for x in dff['Customer ID'].unique()]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False,port=1217)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, will each of the dropdown menu also able to work individually?

Comment: @beginofwork: I think you can check my previous answer, it also can work individually.

Comment: and also how to let the dropdown menu automatically show the value?

Comment: As I said, firstly you should add options for dropdown first then use callback to return new options for them. And if you want it be dependent and also work individually, you should add detail conditions in your callback. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74173240/dynamic-dropdown-with-streamlit-or-dash/74202321#74202321

Comment: added options in the `dcc.Dropdown` but still not able to work individually

Comment: if only one of the dropdown menu want to work individually, also need to setup the `!= ` and `==`  for all the dropdown's callback or only the one?

Comment: @beginofwork: Hm so just use callback for this dropdown.